# asp.net core identity pages (Razor class library) - Need them in spanish

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to implement a website which will only be in use by Spanish speaking users.
I created a new asp.net core web application using individual user accounts (stored in app).

So far so good. The only problem is that the Identity Pages (Register, login, etc..) all display in English.

I would like to have these pages display in Spanish with the least amount of effort on my side.

I would like to avoid scaffolding if possible.
I would like to avoid having to localize all strings if possible.

I am hoping this Razor Class Library is available in different cultures.

So far I have unfortunately not been able to find a localized version of the Identity Pages in Spanish.

Does anyone know if they are at all available?

Thanks!

Comment: I am using asp.net core 2.1

Comment: See this blog post on how to add localization to asp.net core identity https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/damienbod.com/2018/07/03/adding-localization-to-the-asp-net-core-identity-pages/amp/